# Does the Postgres 9.4.9 update fix MultiXactId "does no longer exist" in addition to "has not been created yet" errors?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Postgres 9.4.9 has a fix in it's release notes which reads (emphasis mine):

> Prevent possible failure when vacuuming multixact IDs in an installation that has been pg_upgrade'd from pre-9.3 (Andrew Gierth, Álvaro Herrera)
>
> **The *usual* symptom** of this bug is errors like "MultiXactId NNN has not been created yet -- apparent wraparound".

I am currently chasing errors in PG 9.4.5 which read:

```
2019-10-19 15:37:17 EDT [13024]: [1-1] ERROR:  MultiXactId 1074790449 does no longer exist -- apparent wraparound
```

Does the above fix in PG 9.4.9 address the error I am getting?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143516/postgres-multixactid-error - This question led me to look at PG 9.4.9 . I have tried to trace through the old mailing list threads to determine the answer to my own question but I'm not immediately seeing this one way or the other.

Comment: Good question. I'd assume that it could lead to both of these errors, but I am not sure. You should always install the latest minor release anyway; running 9.4.9 borders on criminal negligence. Try and see!

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to PG 9.6.8. This particular environment is a legacy application that runs on an "appliance" style deployment so I'm forced into only updating to certain versions. 9.6.8 was the smallest increment I could take.

The initially appeared to have solved the `MultiXactId xxxx does no longer exist` problem with some simple queries. Subsequent queries to create indexes failed with the original error.

Comment: You [should really be upgrading](https://why-upgrade.depesz.com/show?from=9.6.8&to=9.6.15&keywords=) to the _latest_ 9.6 version.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @a_horse_with_no_name . Once this wraparound problem is solved, there is some version of PG 10 that I can upgrade to and I'll be making plans to push it forward.